# Producing a list of edges sorted by the Jaccard index of their endpoints in IGraph

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, igraph, similarity

I need some help in figuring out how to sort edges by the Jaccard index of their endpoints in the `C` interface of `igraph`.

I've been able to compute the all-pairs Jaccard indices, but I just want the list of Jaccard indices of the adjacent vertices.
In my case I'm using the Zachary karate club network that has `34` vertices and `78` edges.

```
igraph_t graph;
igraph_famous(&graph,"Zachary"); // load a graph
igraph_write_graph_edgelist(&graph,stderr); // print it to stderr

igraph_matrix_t res; // contains the all-pairs jaccard indices
igraph_matrix_init(&res, igraph_vcount(&graph),igraph_vcount(&graph));
igraph_matrix_resize(&res, igraph_vcount(&graph),igraph_vcount(&graph));
// vertices iterator, to select all vertices
igraph_vs_t all_vertices;
igraph_vs_all(&all_vertices);

igraph_similarity_jaccard(&graph,&res, all_vertices, IGRAPH_ALL,false);
igraph_matrix_print(&res);
```

From that matrix I would like to get and edge selector that, like in the Kruskal algorithm, returns the edges sorted in decreasing order by the Jaccard index of their endpoints.

I think that in order to get only the adjacent vertices, I need to iterate on edges and compute it manually, but I find it very difficult to accomplish this task using igraph.

This in general should apply for any other structural similarity measure that appears in igraph.

Has someone some idea how to implement it, without relying on external data structures?

Answer (score 2):

> I think that in order to get only the adjacent vertices, I need to iterate on edges and compute it manually

No, you don't, you can simply use [`igraph_neighbors`](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Basic.html#igraph_neighbors) to get the adjacent vertices of any given vertex. Then you can iterate over this vector, and get the corresponding values from the Jaccard similarity matrix. Actually, this is even better: take the vector you get from `igraph_neighbors`, convert it into a regular C array using [`igraph_vector_copy_to`](http://igraph.org/c/doc/ch07.html#igraph_vector_copy_to) and then sort the C array with [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) and a comparator function that compares not the vertex indices but the corresponding similarity values from the Jaccard similarity matrix. Finally, if you really need an edge selector, use [`igraph_es_pairs`](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Iterators.html#igraph_es_pairs) to construct an edge selector from the endpoints (which are now sorted)

Comment: I've solved using `igraph_similarity_jaccard_es(&graph, &edges_sim, igraph_ess_all(IGRAPH_EDGEORDER_FROM), IGRAPH_TOTAL, false);` where `edges_sim` is a vector with `|E|` entries. 
Then I've copied the content of `edges_sim` to a `std::vector< pair<int,double> > and used `std::sort` with this comparator:

`inline bool sort_second( const pair<int,igraph_real_t>& l, const pair<int,igraph_real_t>& r)
{
    if (std::fabs(l.second - r.second)<=1E-6)
    {
        return (rand()%2) == 0;
    }
    else
        return l.second > r.second;
}`